# Understanding forward slashes (first character) on Apache

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I've been looking all over the net but I can't find any info on this particular topic of the usages, and I emphasize the plurality, of forward slash on Apache servers. I think I'm looking in the wrong places but I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. For avoidance of doubt, I am referring to the use of forward slash in the first character.

All of my web files and folders are stored on `/public_html/`. When someone goes to my site, `www.example.com`, they arrive at `/public_html/index.php`.

My folders & files are organised as such:

/public_html/

-- /subfolder1/

------ index.php

------ /subfolder2/

---------- index.php

-- /resources/

------ configuration.php

Basically I've seen two incidences:

1) when I'm use forward slash in the first sub-folder of `/public_html/`, i.e. I have a file, say `/public_html/subfolder1/index.php`, and in this file I have a line that goes (note it starts with /res.. instead of ../res..)

```
include_once '/resources/configuration.php';
```

which retrieves `'configuration.php'` from `/public_html/resources/`.
This is the expected behavior given `'/'` refers to the "root" directory.

2) Now, if I do exactly as the above but for a file two-subfolders down `/public_html/`, for e.g. `/public_html/subfolder1/subfolder2/index.php`, I get an error that says

> Warning: include_once(/resources/configuration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/subfolder1/subfolder2/index.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/resources/configuration.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/example/public_html/subfolder1/subfolder2/index.php on line 2.
>   ERROR: invalid data source name

Why did `'/'` work for (1) but not in (2)?

The same issue also applies to html and javascript resource references.

Comment: What does the two subfolder line look like? Because it should be `/subfolder1/subfolder2/index.php` and work fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your problem before you made all those edits to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think your root is not correct instead use relative path with realpath to get the absolute path.

for test write echo realpath("."); in your site root index.php that will give your realpath for your site

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are including the file in your php code, you need to use the absolute path. So:
`include_once '/public_html/resources/configuration.php';`
should work. However, if you are linking an item, say you had an image in that resources folder, this:
`<img src="/resources/image.jpg">`
would work.